# Deprecated methods and application crashes

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making app which uses just actionBar but application crashes and log gives me error at this point (these are  deprecated) :

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
```

Comment: Paste logcat. These methods are deprecated since API 21. It is android 5.0 are you using lollipop device?

Comment: Can you paste a logcat?

Comment: Actually my logcat is not filtering so it is giving many statements all i knew that that the error is in these codes only

Comment: ActionBar.Tab is not supported from the api 21. See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html

Comment: Maybe use ViewPager or DrawerLayout instead of Tabs?

Comment: Will it work if i decrease my sdk version and how many??? because i am following video tutorial and may be android 5.0 was not release at that time , i have no idea how to use these new methods.

Comment: Try to set holo theme. Not material. If you want to use material theme you must use other navigation type.

Comment: I'm forgot to write to you yesterday. Do not use deprecated methods because it can be removed in the future and your application will crash.